# Angular 4 - modifying style of html element with Renderer 2 and Element.querySelector()

Tags: angular, dom, angular-renderer2

Is it ok to have such on click event handlers in Angular 4 component?

```
 showPhotoDeleteButton( event ) 
    { 
        var photoDeleteButton = (<Element>event.target).querySelector('.photo-delete'); 
        this.renderer.setStyle(photoDeleteButton, "display", "block"); 
    }

    hidePhotoDeleteButton( event ) 
    { 
        var photoDeleteButton = (<Element>event.target).querySelector('.photo-delete'); 
        this.renderer.setStyle(photoDeleteButton, "display", "none"); 
    }
```

As I have read that direct DOM manipulation isn't recommended as Angular is a platform and not always run on browser but also on web workers, etc.

Comment: is `.photo-delete` dom node static?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best aproach is to use ngIf and toggle isDeleteButtonVisible in your events:

```
*ngIf="isDeleteButtonVisible"

https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf
```

You can also use NgClass or NgStyle

```
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass
https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle
https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-ngclass-and-ngstyle
```

For example you can use NgClass and then in your show and hide events change only one property from true to false and have button visible or not

Comment: but i have list of items so I need to have array of boolean flags ?

Comment: you can add property to your item for example item.isDeleteButtonVisible and then use it in each *ngIf for item

Comment: Could you provide some example? I am looping through array of string. Maybe this items should be custom angular components or how can I add it to strings?

Comment: So everything is fine, just instead looping through array of strings loop through  array of object, and when you use string, just use exampleObject.stringPropertyName, if it is just button and for example string for user to read you don't need separated component, now I can't do example give me specific details about what you want and I try but probably not today